# how to open other form after web fullyloaded c#

Tags: c#

How to wait for web page fully loaded then open/create new form2 with webbrowser navigate to another page

I'm trying by checking using igetattribut on loaded site on form 1 but not working because checking is running before web fully loaded

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace bot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webbMain.Navigate("http://asia1.darkorbit.com/");
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var inputElements = webbMain.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement i in inputElements)
            {
                if (i.GetAttribute("name").Equals("username"))
                {
                    i.InnerText = txtUsername.Text;
                }
                if (i.GetAttribute("name").Equals("password"))
                {
                    i.Focus();
                    i.InnerText = txtPassword.Text;
                }
            }

            var buttonElements = webbMain.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement b in inputElements)
            {
                if (b.GetAttribute("className").Equals("bgcdw_button bgcdw_login_form_login"))
                {
                    b.InvokeMember("click");
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Jquery's $document.ready which fires once the page has loaded.

Comment: how to do that ??

Comment: Are you already using JQuery in your application?

Comment: not yet, idk how

Comment: You need to include the Jquery libraries into your project. These files are then referenced as links in each page or on a master / layout page. You can get what you need from https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/. Its the same principle as linking to style sheets. Once done you use the $document.ready command in a script block on your html.

Comment: What you are trying to do won't work. The code you have written runs on the server! You need to run code on the web browser client and make that open a new window. I'll post an answer with the code that will run once you've got JQuery set up.

Comment: I've just noticed in your code that you are using Windows Forms? I'm confused!?